# HTML5 WebWorkers, timed function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get a WebWorker to count to 100 and update a div with the value of I, currently the div just updates straight to 100 and seems to ignore the interval....
**JavaScript (webworker file):**

```
 self.addEventListener('message', function (e) {

        switch (e.data) {

            case 'Hi Worker':
                postMessage('Hi Boss');
                break

            case 'Count to 100':
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                    setInterval(postMessage(i + 1), 1000);
                }

                break;
            default:
                self.postMessage("Not sure how to help with that");
        }

    }, false);
```

**Main file:**

```
           <script>
            var worker = new Worker('worker.js');

            worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
                console.log("worker said: " + "'" + e.data + "'");
                document.getElementById("workerComms").textContent = "worker said: " + e.data;
            }, false);       

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="worker.postMessage('Hi Worker');return false;">Say 'Hi Worker'</button>
            <button onclick="worker.postMessage('Count to 100');return false;">Count to 100</button>

            <div id="workerComms">Things workers say...</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setInterval(postMessage(i + 1), 1000);` **calls** `postMessage(i + 1)` and then passes the return value into `setInterval`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes the return value into `foo`.

Instead:

1. You want to pass a function reference to `setInterval`
2. You want to use `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`
3. You want to vary the timeout, because otherwise they'll all happen stacked on top of each other one second later

Something *like*:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    setTimeout(postMessage.bind(window, i), 1000 * i);
}
```

would probably do it. That schedules 100 timers, at one-second intervals. It uses `postMessage.bind(window, i)` to create a function that, when called, will all `postMessage` with `this` set to `window` and passing in `i` as the first argument. I did `i` from `1` to `100` rather than `0` to `99` to avoid having to add `1` to it in both places I used it.

Alternately, you could ditch the `for` loop entirely and use `setInterval` or a chained series of `setTimeout`. Here's the `setInterval`:

```
var i = 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    postMessage(++i);
    if (i >= 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
```